# memcached instead of the MySQL Query cache

Tags: mysql, query-cache

I have busy mysql database with too many user and over 200G database , I see in my mysql adviser following comment :

```
Recommendation:
You are using the MySQL Query cache with a fairly high traffic database. It might be worth considering to use memcached instead of the MySQL Query cache, especially if you have multiple slaves.

Justification:
The query cache is enabled and the server receives 2274 queries per second. This rule fires if there is more than 100 queries per second.
```

How can use memcached in front of mysql server ? and if enable memcache need to change php (and other) scripts ?

Edit :

```
mysql> show global status like '%qc%';
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 14355    |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 29666144 |
| Qcache_hits             | 71880172 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 26772214 |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 9488510  |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 3839367  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 24712    |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 100648   |
+-------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It means changing your application to manage its caches directly. Check the status info about the query cache too - `show global status like '%qc%';` to see how its doing for now.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'Uptime';` so we know how to scale them.

Comment: And `Com_select`.

Comment: hits/inserts is about 3:1.  That indicates the QC is of some use.

Comment: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it." -- are there any other indications that MySQL is having trouble keeping up?